# Using annotation @Sql, is it possible to execute scripts in Class level before Method level?

Tags: spring, spring-test

I want to execute two scripts before every test method, but i also want to define some scripts to execute before specific methods. Using Spring framework and `@Sql` annotations, is it possible?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/WEB-INF/application-context.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql({ "/database/drop_schema.sql", "/database/create_schema.sql" })
public class CentralServiceTestCase {
 
  // I want to run "drop_schema.sql", "create_schema.sql" 
  // and "basic_data.sql" here
  @Test
  @Sql({ "/database/basic_data.sql" })       
  public void processActionWithSuccess() {
    
  }

  // I want to run only "drop_schema.sql" and "create_schema.sql" here
  @Test 
  public void anotherTestMethod() {
  
  }

}
```

Running this code **only** `basic_data.sql` is executed. How to solve this problem?

Do I  will have to remove the `@Sql` anotation from class and replicate it for each method with `/database/drop_schema.sql` and `/database/create_schema.sql` defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This is now possible in the upcoming Spring Framework **5.2** release via the new `@SqlMergeMode` annotation (see [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sqlmergemode) for **5.2.0.RC1**).

---

The 2nd paragraph of the Javadoc for `@Sql` explicitly states:

> Method-level declarations override class-level declarations.

This is also documented in the [Executing SQL scripts declaratively with @Sql](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-executing-sql-declaratively) section of the reference manual.

Thus, no, it is unfortunately not possible to have scripts declared via `@Sql` at the class level be executed if `@Sql` is also defined at the method level.

If you would like for Spring to support such combinations, please [create a JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) requesting this feature and select the `Test` *Component*.

Thanks!

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Or [SPR-16021](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16021). It would be really nice feature.

Comment: This is now possible in the upcoming Spring Framework 5.2 release via the new `@SqlMergeMode` annotation. See update in answer.