# Reading.sql file from custom location other than resouces folder using @sql spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, java-resources

Hi  I have written test case using spring data jpa test . Test case are running fine when i put `data.sql` and `schema.sql` file inside test/resources folder even though without using `@Sql` annotation because of default behaviour of spring boot test.

But my requirement is that i have one folder which is parallel to main and test folder i.e integrationTest where my **data-h2.sql and schema-h2.sql** file is residing . Problem is that I am not able to read these sql file using `@Sql` Annotation. how to give the path so that i can read sql file from any given custom location

Below is the folder structure and code for reference

[image]

**Code**

```
@DataJpaTest
@Sql(scripts={"/integrationTest/schema-h2.sql", "/integrationTest/data-h2.sql"})
public class AbcRepositoryTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

}
```

**Error**

08:44:45.329 [Test worker] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 90079, SQLState: 90079
08:44:45.329 [Test worker] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Schema "TEST" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: what do you mean by custom location? What is the absolute path of your `schema-h2.sql`

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai absolute path is /data/sfsf/workspace/timeevent/tenant-creation/8669/online/time/src/integrationTest/resources/schema-h2.sql   where online is the root project under which time is child project

Comment: Try `file:src/integrationTest/resources/schema-h2.sql` . If it doesn't work `file:/data/sfsf/workspace/timeevent/tenant-creation/8669/online/time/src/integrationTest/resources/schema-h2.sql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution for  the question i have posted after struggling 3 to 4 hour
we need to use SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener in order to read @Sql Scripts from custom location of your choice and put DirtiesContext so that @Sql script run for each of your test case.

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = {"file:src/integrationTest/resources/schema-h2.sql","file:src/integrationTest/resources/data-h2.sql"})
public class AbcRepositoryTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
}
```

UsefulLink help to solve the issue

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18929

[How can Spring's test annotation @Sql behave like @BeforeClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775560/how-can-springs-test-annotation-sql-behave-like-beforeclass)

[Using annotation @Sql, is it possible to execute scripts in Class level before Method level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871817/using-annotation-sql-is-it-possible-to-execute-scripts-in-class-level-before-m)